# Stopping my play from going out of camara view (adding bounds) 2d game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm trying to make a where you are on blocks and have to jump from block to block, trying to avoid bombs.

[image: Picture of game.]

I'm trying to do so he can't go outside the camera. I can't seem to find any way of stopping him from doing that. I don't want him to freeze, just not go outside. I have tried to ad blocks at the side and adding box collider, but it doesn't work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide any code, maybe the following (pseudo) code may help:

```
// camera view horizontal check
if (player.X < cameraView.X || player.X + player.Width > cameraview.X + cameraView.Width) 
{
    player.MoveX();
}

// camera view vertical check
if (player.Y < cameraView.Y || player.Y + player.Height > cameraview.Y + cameraView.Height) 
{
    player.MoveY();
}
```

Comment: When I try that in the update, I get an error that says:
Error CS0103: The name 'player' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) (Assembly-CSharp)

Then I tried creating a public Transform called player.
But when i do that it just says 
Error CS1061: 'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'X' and no extension method 'X' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform' could be found 
 
Error CS0103: The name 'cameraView' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) (Assembly-CSharp)

Am I missing something or I'm I just stupid?

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine just found a way to do it.
He put my game objects and added coliders.

Sorry for wasting your time...

Comment: no worries magnus. a fe pointers though.  You should always have aplayer tag, they come in in handy, look into tags. also, if you attach your camera to the character, it will follow him so he cant walk off screen, allowing you to build bigger levels.

Comment: I will. Thank you